# React Native Focused-Based/Spatial Navigation

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Is there a way to emulate what [iOS's switch control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201370) does in a React Native app without turning it on at the OS level? If not, is there a way to turn on Switch Control from the app?

**Update:** Spatial/Focused-Based navigation is what I was looking for but didn't know enough about the space to know the correct terminology. See a solution below

Answer (score 0):

This library seems like it will do the trick but I haven't tested it yet:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-spatial-navigation

There seems to be much better support/solutions for web development:
https://github.com/NoriginMedia/react-spatial-navigation